# Dynamically/Recursively Normalize Data while Iterating through a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, recursion, normalize

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
my_dict = {
    '_id': '12powensjdm683ma23',
    'data': {
      'account': 'FUNDING',
      'form': {
        'accounts': {
          'credit': {
            'name': 'JOBEN BETETI BORGES',
            'account_number': 'YYYYYYYY',
            'address': {
              'line3': '0.',
              'line2': 'rial, Santo André, SP, BR,09080-50',
              'line1': '1600 APTO.51 TORRE 3 Avenida Indust'
            }
          },
          'receiving': {
            'name': 'THE BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON',
            'aba_number': 'XXXXXXXX',
            'address': {
              'line1': 'NEW YORK, NY, US',
              'line2': '',
              'line3': ''
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to create a function that will loop through each key value pair and determine if the value has "offending" values like the é in the municipality Santo André.

```
line2': 'rial, Santo André, SP, BR, 09080-50',
```

If it is, then we will normalize the value to a normal e. So it'd look like this:

```
line2': 'rial, Santo Andre, SP, BR, 09080-50',
```

In addition to this, I would like this to be dynamic, so that the code doesn't have to explicitly look for `my_dict['data']['form']['accounts']['credit']` or `my_dict['line2']`. It should just loop through each key value pair, and if that value is "offending", then update it (I have other dictionaries that I need to update in a similar way, but their keys, lengths and depths are varying).

I think I really just need a way to loop through every level of a dictionary that has any number of particular levels.

I initially thought to recursively run the function through this dynamic_input() function I have but the input takes string values. However, with the recursive function, the values might also be another dict. `dynamic_input()` currently takes in a string value.

```
def dynamic_input(input):
    ''' Clean the given dynamic input of any offending formats or characters.
        Parameters: str(input)
        Returns: str(cleaned_input)
    '''
    # remove excessive spaces
    input = " ".join(input.split())

    # remove undesired characters
    input = re.sub("\\n|\\r|\\t|'|\"", '', input)

    # special character conversion
    input = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', input)
    input = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', '', input)

    # return
    return input
```

Comment: Go through the key value pairs and if the value is a dict then recurse?

Comment: Dump that dictionary to string `json.dumps`, fix the characters, and load again. I guess better than iterating

Answer (score 0):

since I cannot comment yet, I will post the answer I've found [here](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-iterate-over-nested-dictionary-dict-of-dicts/)

```
my_dict = {
    '_id': '12powensjdm683ma23',
    'data': {
    'account': 'FUNDING',
    'form': {
        'accounts': {
        'credit': {
            'name': 'JOBEN BETETI BORGES',
            'account_number': 'YYYYYYYY',
            'address': {
            'line3': '0.',
            'line2': 'rial, Santo André, SP, BR,09080-50',
            'line1': '1600 APTO.51 TORRE 3 Avenida Indust'
            }
        },
        'receiving': {
            'name': 'THE BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON',
            'aba_number': 'XXXXXXXX',
            'address': {
            'line1': 'NEW YORK, NY, US',
            'line2': '',
            'line3': ''
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}


def nested_dict_pairs_iterator(dict_obj):
    ''' This function accepts a nested dictionary as argument
        and iterate over all values of nested dictionaries
    '''
    # Iterate over all key-value pairs of dict argument
    for key, value in dict_obj.items():
        # Check if value is of dict type
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # If value is dict then iterate over all its values
            for pair in  nested_dict_pairs_iterator(value):
                yield (key, *pair)
        else:
            # If value is not dict type then yield the value
            yield (key, value)

#Loop through all key-value pairs of a nested dictionary    
for pair in nested_dict_pairs_iterator(my_dict):
    print(pair)
```

output:

```
('_id', '12powensjdm683ma23')
('data', 'account', 'FUNDING')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'credit', 'name', 'JOBEN BETETI BORGES')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'credit', 'account_number', 'YYYYYYYY')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'credit', 'address', 'line3', '0.')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'credit', 'address', 'line2', 'rial, Santo André, SP, BR,09080-50')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'credit', 'address', 'line1', '1600 APTO.51 TORRE 3 Avenida Indust')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'receiving', 'name', 'THE BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'receiving', 'aba_number', 'XXXXXXXX')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'receiving', 'address', 'line1', 'NEW YORK, NY, US')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'receiving', 'address', 'line2', '')
('data', 'form', 'accounts', 'receiving', 'address', 'line3', '')
```

You can implement your replacing stuff of unaccepted characters in the function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a simple function, that would recursively map dict values to a function. Here's how I'd define one and how you could use it:

```
from typing import Callable
import collections.abc

def dict_rec_map(d: dict, func: Callable[[str], str]):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, collections.abc.Mapping):
            d[k] = dict_rec_map(v, func) # recursive call
        else:
            d[k] = func(v)
    return d

updated = dict_rec_map(my_dict, dynamic_input)
```

Using your data and function, this returned to me:

```
{
    "_id": "12powensjdm683ma23",
    "data": {
        "account": "FUNDING",
        "form": {
            "accounts": {
                "credit": {
                    "account_number": "YYYYYYYY",
                    "address": {
                        "line1": "1600 APTO.51 TORRE 3 Avenida Indust",
                        "line2": "rial, Santo Andre, SP, BR,09080-50",
                        "line3": "0."
                    },
                    "name": "JOBEN BETETI BORGES"
                },
                "receiving": {
                    "aba_number": "XXXXXXXX",
                    "address": {
                        "line1": "NEW YORK, NY, US",
                        "line2": "",
                        "line3": ""
                    },
                    "name": "THE BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The algorithm is good, but naming the function `dict_rec_map` is deceiving, since your function modifies the input dict, whereas functions called `map` are usually expected to produce an output without modifying the input.